# Git- Filter Branch Command Deletion of Commits After Certain Date

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I've been asked to remove commits after a certain date on of our projects at my company.

I've read the git filter-branch man pages and I am puzzled on how I could run a command in a repository that would delete all commit history after a certain date. I have cloned a copy of the repository on my local machine W7 (64bit) Running Cygwin I would like to test the command before I make a copy of the project on the remote server itself.

-Thanks

Sulman

Comment: Are the commits out of date order? If they're in order, you don't need to use filter-branch at all, just reset the branch back to where itw as on that certain date.

Comment: Use MSysGit instead of Cygwin. If you want a better git that's more linux-like, use a vm with ubuntu server on it or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `filter-branch`. You can simply reset the references to the latest commit in history that satisfies the criteria. For each reference do

```
git push . -f <someearlier commit>:branch-name
```

Then update the central repo with

```
git push -f
```

or if you are not tracking the branches, specify each one:

```
git push -f origin branch-name
```

or automate with

```
git branch -r | sed ... # etc, etc
```